# Png image is displayed on android 7.0 mobile phone, but it is not displayed properly on 8.0 mobile phone, why？

Tags: android, png, android-8.0-oreo

Png image is displayed on android 7.0 mobile phone, but it is not displayed properly on 8.0 mobile phone, why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the tint color of image?

Comment: I didn't change the tint

Comment: It's unclear whether this is a programming question, or just an OS-level question (which would be off-topic here). If programming, please edit your question to show your code and more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, it is a problem with the wide color gamut of the picture. If the ui designer gives a wide color gamut picture, it is necessary to support the wide color gamut in the code, the picture can be displayed normally.